# Any case where simultaneous multithreading is worse than normal case?

Tags: cpu

Is there any chance of SMT (simultaneous multithrading) giving worse performance than normal CPU?

For example, is it possible for normal CPU to two programs one by one to have better performance than running these two programs simultaneously on CPU that supports 2-way SMT?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to clear up the last sentance (a little). It sounds like your referring to running one program at a time, finishing the work on one first, then seperately working with the second program, or running 2 programs at the same time . It would also be important to indicate if the intention here is programs that are working the available cores of the processor , or just (mostly) parked, and if the programs themselves are multithreaded making use of all the cores.

Comment: What i meant was to find an example of the situation where SMT of two independent programs show worse performance than executing programs one after the other.

Comment: **Please do not repost the same question.** If you need to bump an existing post, please edit it instead,